# Database relations query

Tags: asp.net, mysql, sql, oracle, database-design

I have two database tables
[image: Ticket table]

[image: Tax table]

this is a sample database of a Ticketing system.

Figure 1: Sample table of air ticket.
Figure 2: Sample table of tax.

***Requirement:***
When ticket is made from the interface, it has multiple taxes of different names every time.
How can I store this information i.e. 'n' number of taxes for each ticket with different names every time.

I have tried to make many to many relationship but the problem is:
For each ticket if the tax is not setup, then need to add the tax first.

Any optimal solution for this?

Comment: if  you divide this  table into 3 table like  1 for tax another for generating a unique ticket id  and 3 rd table  where u will use ur uniqe ticket id as foreign key and there will will be a fild tax id and this 3rd table for each ticket id there will be as many rows as equal to the number of taxes applicable , so when u will generate price as summation of tax

Comment: You are talking about many to many right?? If yes then say one is making ticket and he does not have tax added in tax table, then he will need to add the tax first, then continue with the ticket. But this is very tiring solution for the end user.... to make bunch of tax setup for each ticket.

Comment: I am not quite sure I understand your problem

Comment: @Saad khatri :  i am not able to understand why end user that is the buyer of ticket will need to add tax for his ticket , this is not his  responsibility, during buying ticket total ticket price included tax should display.

if you are talking about the airlines  company who will relate available taxes which will be applicable for ticket then  he can certainly add taxes first then do the rest of the thing. 

can you please exaplin the real scenario with example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "the problem is: For each ticket if the tax is not setup, then need to
>   add the tax first."

This is not a real-life problem.  In real life governments declare taxes well in advance of collecting them,  This gives organizations sufficient time to amend their systems which need to handle taxes.  Tax is never a surprise.

> "But this is very tiring solution for the end user.... to make bunch
>   of tax setup for each ticket"

This sort of thing is reference data, and is the duty of the system developer (hint: that's you) to populate the reference data tables.  Or at least provide a screen where the user can create or amend various taxes.  This is a different function from defining a ticket type.

The Ticket Creation screen should have a drop-down list (or similar widget) displaying all the existing taxes, which allows the user to pick the relevant one(s).  If you reall think it's necessary you can include a link to the Create Tax screen, but that really is a very confusing workflow.

---

If the commentators are correct, and this is a ticket *purchasing* function, then your design is seriously wrong.  Sales taxes must be included automatically to the cost of the purcahse as part of the transaction.  Otherwise nobody would pay any tax.